# Traveling to USA from Morocco through Barcelona do I need a transit visa If I am asked to collect my chec-luggage (using different airline company)

Tags: usa, schengen, transit-visas, barcelona, moroccan-citizens

I am contacting you guys concerning one of the problems that I believe I will have them during my trip through Barcelona Airport.

I am traveling from Morocco (CMN Airport, Casablanca) to Indianapolis, USA. I have the USA visa and I found out that I may have problems ( I am sure that as Moroccan I don't need a Transit visa thought Spain), but in my electronic flight ticket I have to stay in Barcelona Airport for 6h and 35min and at the same time I have to get my checked luggage and I have to register them again in the same airport (Same Terminal 1 (Arrival/Departure). 
My question is: do I am going to apply for a transit visa if I am going to stay 7hours in the airport waiting for my second flight (Even if I am asked to search for my checked luggage and I am asked to register them again which means that I have to pass through the security check I believe).

I hope I am being clear enough with my question and the situation description. 
I would like to thank you in advance for your time and comprehension.

Comment: Looks lie your flight is on 2 separate tickets. To collect luggage you need to go through immigration.

Comment: I have only one ticket but with 3 different airlines the Morrocan airline/ The Spanish airline and American airline from Boston airport to Indianapolis (from my E-ticket they mentioned that I most collect my Checking luggage because I am not going to travel with the same airline).

Comment: Are you sure you have to re-check the luggage at BCN?  If not, you just stay in the departure/transit area of Barcelona airport.  You will definitely have to collect and recheck at BOS because of customs and immigration.

Comment: Yes for sure they said that I have to collect my luggage and re-check in order to get my second boarding pass (No online check-in available).

Comment: If that's the case, you will need a Transit Visa for your stay at BCN because you can only collect your baggage after immigration.

Comment: @Johns-305 Not a transit visa, but a regular visitor visa

Comment: @Coke Timatic used the term Transit Visa.  In my Answer, was purposefully not so specific.

Comment: @Johns-305 THe airport transit visa doesn't let you clear immigration either, that's the thing, and the B-type transit visa, which was meant for this, is long abolished

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the valuable information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have to collect bags or enter Spain for any other reason, you will need a short-stay (type C) Schengen visa.  Baggage collection is after immigration and there is no way around this.

If the airlines could check the bags through to BOS, you would've been able to stay in the departure/transit area without needing a visa, at least according to Timatic.

Comment: You mean that If they ask me to collect my luggage it means that I most ass from the immigration which means that I have to apply for a transit visa even if I am not required to apply based on my Moroccan Passeport ?

Comment: @KhadirLazar Timatic says Moroccan Passports need a Visa for Spain.

Comment: No, I am not talking about the visa one I am, talking about the Transit that will allow me to just switch terminals for a connection flight.
So based on your info I most need a visa because I am going to pass through the immegration ?

Comment: @KhadirLazar You need a Visa to enter Spain, be it is Transit, Tourist, Business Visa.  Transit is just type of very short term Visa.  If you can stay in the departure/transit area, you don't need a Visa.  But, if you have to collect baggage, you need a Visa. *According to Timatic.*

Comment: @KhadirLazar "So based on your info I most need a visa because I am going to pass through the immegration ?" Exactly

Comment: Schengen airport transit visas (type A) do not allow entry into the Schengen zone; they require the bearer to remain on the "international" side of the passport control checkpoints.  Schengen "transit visas" (type B) have not existed for some years now.  The traveler needs a short-stay (type C) visa.  (A type D visa would work, too, but the traveler does not qualify for one since there is no plan to stay for a long time in any Schengen country.)

Comment: @phoog I really hope you didn't Downvote because that's just wrong.

Comment: @Johns-305 I downvoted because you answered the question "do I need a transit visa" in the affirmative, but that is incorrect because the only transit visa available is the airport transit visa, which is not sufficient to recheck luggage.  The correct answer is "no, you need a regular short-stay visa."  Furthermore, a Moroccan traveler does not require, and so probably cannot apply for, an airport transit visa.

Comment: @Johns-305 No, it's you that misinterpret TIMATIC. THe "Country - Transit visa" isn't a specific statement for Spain, just an indication that the following listing is about transit requirements for Spain. Usually a transit visa (or even a visa-free transit provision) is sufficient for cases like these, but not in Schengen.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, but that is a laughably narrow and pedantic interpretation of the question.  That Answer is, OP needs a Visa which I state very clearly.  As I also note, the term Transit is still out there.

Comment: @Johns-305 But again, a Schengen airport transit visa will be useless, as that too requires you to stay in the transit zone, and won't let you enter the country to pick up any bags. It is thus a regular short-stay visa OP needs

Comment: @phoog Nope, sorry.  It's not an interpretation, it's what is says.  Apparently you didn't read my Answer either because I never said "Transit" in the Asnwer.  Just that OP needs a Visa, which is 100% correct.

Comment: It's not laughably narrow or pedantic if someone reads your answer, sees the word "yes," and therefore applies for an airport transit visa for this itinerary or anything similar.  That would leave them in a position of having inadequate documents to complete their trip.

Comment: @Johns-305 Edited your answer. It's now correct and I've changed my downvote to an upvote

Comment: @Coke It was never wrong, and the quote is from a well know Timatic site.  Loving this because is just another example of wrong and misleading Downvotes I can point to.

Comment: @Coke Thank you for handling this the right way.  A comment mentioning "Transit" Visas are not a real thing (despite Timatic) would have also worked.  I would have been happy to edit.

Comment: thank you guys for your help I really appreciate everything

Comment: @KhadirLazar You may want to accept this answer by pressing the button below the down arrow